# How to sum duplicate result in table

Tags: sql

I create tables from another set. In the model column, I have two items, Credit Risk and Eq, assigned to each item. I also have a Country column where I have a list of countries where each item is located. However, I have a lot of duplicate results e.g. 100 Credit Risk for England. I would like, for example, that Credit Risk for England was only once and the results were summed up (Price) and that the position for Credit Risk was assigned only once for each country. I don't know how to do this my basics in SQL.

```
SELECT 

OB,
Country, 
Price,
case
when 'Credit' = 1 then 'Credit Risk'
when 'Equities' = 0 then 'Eq Risk'
end as Model

from finance;
```

EDIT:
After aggreging : I would like get one result for examole to CH if CDR CCF is 1 .

[image]

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want. Also tag your question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate the results using `Group By`.

```
SELECT ob,
   country,
   Sum(price) AS Price,
   CASE
     WHEN 'Credit' = 1 THEN 'Credit Risk'
     WHEN 'Equities' = 0 THEN 'Eq Risk'
   end        AS Model
FROM   finance
GROUP  BY ob,
      country,
      price,
      credit equities
```

Comment: I have problem its still not helped . I edited y post

Comment: I used select distinct Thanks :) dor help

Comment: You need to aggregate all the non-grouped fields.  So, in your example above, you would need to group by Reporting_date, CRD_CCF, Kod and Original, and then SUM, MAX etc on Korekta.